# How do you print the name of a variable?

Tags: python

Is it possible to print a variable in python that is a saved as a variable. Here is an example as it is reasonably hard to describe:

```
Variable1 = 1

Variable2 = Variable1

Variable3 = Variable2

print(Variable3)
```

How would I make it so that when I print Variable3 the output is:

```
Variable2
```

Instead of being:

```
1
```

Without having Variable2 in the print brackets.

Comment: Why do you want to print `"Variable2"` and not `"Variable1"`?

Comment: If you want the names, then you need to store them as strings.  You could keep all of them as a `dict`.

Comment: Can you share how exactly this question is relevant to the tag [tag:currency]?

Comment: Objects have no knowledge of the variables that may be referring to them. No, there isn't a good way to do this. If you want to *associate strings with some other object*, then you need to write code to maintain that association e.g. with a `dict`, or some other container (a list of tuples?)

Comment: You can also use ..... a,b,c = 1,1,1 ...... print(c) ..... --> 1

Comment: You *can* get the memory reference id for a variable which will show if two variables point to the same memory location as `id(Variable1)`. But again, this returns a numeric id, not a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

you can define your own function for this purpose:

```
import re
import inspect


def varname(p):
  for line in inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe().f_back)[3]:
    nam = re.search(r'\bvarname\s*\(\s*([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)\s*\)', line)
    if nam:
      return nam.group(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Variable1 = 1

    Variable2 = Variable1

    Variable3 = Variable2

    print(varname(Variable3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the names of all variables that reference the same data as Variable3 (including 'Variable3') by searching the locals (or globals) for the id() of its value:

```
print([k for k,v in locals().items() if id(v)==id(Variable3)])

['Variable1', 'Variable2', 'Variable3']
```